# How to generate a shell script & use shell variable defined in generated shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I have a shell script that generates and runs a shell script. I need to get hold of a variable that is set once the generated script is run. testVar script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "#!/bin/bash" > testGen
echo "somePid='12345' # this is actually set by a program" >> testGen
echo "echo \"somePid set to: \${somePid}\"" >> testGen

/bin/bash ./testGen  # execute the generated script

echo "somePid after exec: ${somePid}" # how to get the ${somePid}?
```

How can I get ${somePid} ? Expected output:

```
$ ./testVar
somePid set to: 12345
somePid after exec: 12345
```

Comment: You would have to `source` the other script (or use the equivalent `.` command), so it runs in the same shell. But... why create another script rather than just executing commands directly? It seems like an overcomplicated and fragile way to do things.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! . ./testgen works. This is a simplified example, the actual script for computational fluid dynamics is large, and dictates this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. first of all, you can store process id in file, in Linux it is very popular idea to store pid to PIDFILE ( file.pid ). Many linux processes do that, storing their pidfiles in /var/run or in /tmp. Then you can read pid from the file using cat command
2. You can run other script using "." or "source" command - in this case other script will be executed in the same shell process, and any variables which will set by other script will be avalable after completion

Comment: Thank you, checking this as the accepted answer. I was aware of storing the pid file, but was looking for a simpler way. I forgot about the "source" command.

For others: In above example, replace:
```/bin/bash ./testGen```
with:
```. ./testGen```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the PID in a file, for instance

```
# This is in your testVar
echo 'echo $somePid >somePid' >> testGen
```

After running your program, you can retrieve it from there:

```
./testVar
echo "somePid after exec: $(<somePid)"
```